# Odd subfield of cyclotomic field with 2-ramification

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, ramification

I have a tower of fields $\mathbb{Q} \subset L \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{m})$ with the following hypothesis. $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$ is odd, $2$ is the only rational prime that ramifies in $L$. I want to prove that $L=\mathbb{Q}$. I tried to compute the discriminant of $L$ in relation to that of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{m})$, but didn't manage to do that. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m=2^k \prod_j p_j^{d_j}$.

$\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ is totally ramified at the primes of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{m/{p_j}^{d_j}})$ above $p_j$ so $L\subset \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ is unramified at $p_j$ implies that $L\subset \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{m/p_j^{d_j}})$.

Whence $$L\subset \bigcap_j \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{m/p_j^{d_j}})=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^k})$$

Since $[\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^k}):\Bbb{Q}]= 2^{k-1}$ then $[L:\Bbb{Q}]$ is odd means that $L=\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a hunch this was the way to go. Where can I find in the literature that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ is totally ramified at the primes above $p_j$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{m/p_j^d})$? Because I've been looking for such a result but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: I'm thinking that $p_j$ is unramified in $K=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{m/p_j^{d_j}})$ so that it stays an uniformizer of the localization of $O_K$ at $\mathfrak{P}$, and hence $\Phi_{p_j^d}(x+1)$ (which is Eisenstein at $p_j$) stays Eisenstein at $\mathfrak{P}$. Otherwise you can factorize $p_j$ in each cyclotomic field, using that $x^{m/p_j^{d_j}}-1\bmod p_j$ is separable and $\Phi_{p_j^d}(x+1)$ is Eisenstein.

Comment: I have another doubt. How the fact that $L$ is unramified at $p_j$ implies $L\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{m/p_{j}^{d_j}})$?

Comment: Well, if $E/K,F/K$ are unramified at a prime of $O_K$ then so is $EF/K$. Do you like the uniformizers of the localization? I prefer $p$-adic extensions. $F/K$ unramified means that the extension is obtained by adjoining the root of a polynomial separable modulo $(\pi)$ (the uniformizer) and that $\pi$ stays an uniformizer in the localizations of the extension, and since $EF/F$ is obtaining by adding the root of a polynomial separable modulo $(\pi)$, it is unramified, $\pi$ stays uniformizer in $O_{EF}$ so $EF/K$ is unramified at $(\pi)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as I am not very accustomed with ramification theory, I still cannot properly understand. Are you saying that taking $L$ and $F = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{m/p_j^{d_j}})$ both unramified at $p_j$ we get that their compositum $LF$ is still unramified over $p_j$ and moreover as an extension of $F$ is unramified at each prime in $L$ above $p_j$ which is not possible unless $LF = F$ becuse at "some point" those primes above $p_j$ are totally ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{m})$? Am I missing something?